# Empty array can be cast to array of any type

Tags: arrays, swift, casting

It seems empty arrays in Swift can be cast to any array type.

See the following example:

```
var obj = [Int]()

// compiler warns that this cast always fails, but this evaluates to true
print(obj is [String]) 

obj.append(3)

// This evaluates to false as expected
print(obj is [String])
```

This is easily verifiable in a playground, but will also happen in compiled code.  Is this a known issue?

Comment: I find it even more interesting that the first `print` shows `true` even if `obj` is declared as `var obj: [Int] = []`.

Comment: Wouldn't `var obj = [Int]()` and `var obj: [Int] = []` be considered equivalent?

Comment: In the end yes but one has an explicit type declaration and the other has an implicit (inferred) type declaration.

Comment: For context, I had this come up in a switch where I compare the type of the object against different types in my cases.

Comment: Related bug report (for the spurious warning, but the reason why the cast succeeds is also mentioned in the comments): https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6192. Swift also has this behaviour for casting between nils of different Optional types.

Comment: The line `print(obj as! [String])` also gives a warning but works at runtime. Edit: Seems this is covered as well in the bug linked by @Hamish

Comment: Presumably `obj as [String]` without a forced cast would still return an object of type `[String]` if the array is empty.

Comment: @Hamish Interesting.  It looks like the conclusion is that this is intentional and the compiler warning is wrong.

Comment: I feel this makes type-checking for arrays unreliable ..

Comment: @kid_x I don’t really think a consensus was reached in the bug report whether the cast should actually succeed or not. There are good reasons for and against; on one hand, banning the conversion means that we can have diagnostics to warn about casting to collections of unrelated types, on the other hand, even if it was banned for collections of unrelated type, an intermediate implicit conversion to `[Any]` would make it succeed again.

Comment: @kid_x Actually, the compiler is giving a valid warning. It's the runtime that seems to be lying.

Comment: Got it.  Misread the conversation in the bug report then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Hamish indicated, this is indeed a known issue.  His comment points to bug report https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6192 .

A workaround for this type logic seems to be

`type(of: obj) == [SomeType].self`

To expand on the example above,

```
var obj = [Int]()

obj is [String] // true
type(of: obj) == [String].self // false
type(of: obj) == [Int].self // true

obj.append(3)

obj is [String] // false
type(of: obj) == [String].self // false
```